# Which is more efficient, ops on an absolute path or ops on ref + relative path?

Tags: firebase

Which of these is quicker? Or is there no difference?

Option 1

```
const rootRef = new Firebase(process.env.FIREBASE_URL)
const absolutePath1 = '/foo/bar/hello'
const absolutePath2 = '/foo/bar/yoda'

rootRef.child(absolutePath1).update(...)
rootRef.child(absolutePath2).update(...)
```

Option 2

```
// ref points to '/foo/bar'
ref.child('hello').update(...)
ref.child('yoda').update(...)
```

Comment: The speed of transferring bytes over the internet will vastly eclipse any processing speed of concatenating strings. Thus, there will be no notable difference. Also, these two are no different internally--just two strings to split on / and concatenate accordingly.

Comment: @Kato, yea Mohammed answered the question yesterday.

Comment: @Kato, yea Mohammed answered the question yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relative path calculated with respect to another URI. but absolute path doesn't. There is nothing significant as performance or effiency.

Comment: So you're saying Option1 and Option2 are equally performant? And can you clarify the first statement?

Comment: Both of them equally performant. The path with reference to root directory is called absolute. The path with reference to current directory is called relative. Absolute paths tell the browser precisely where to go.